# Weird Train/Test accuracy in graph neural network model and Runtimeerror: pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I faced some very weird accuracy with my graph neural network. My model is :

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
         self.conv1 = ChebConv(132, 32,20) # input layer
         self.conv2 = ChebConv(32, 12,20)
    def forward(self, data):  #define forward network
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
Model=Net()
print(Model)
```

Training and Test function is:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=5e-4)
def train():
    model.train()
    cum_loss = 0
    for data in dataset:  # Iterate in batches over the training dataset.
        data = data.to(device)
        out = model(data) #, data.batch)  # Perform a single forward pass.
        loss = F.mse_loss(out, data.y)
        #loss = criterion(out, data.y)  # Compute the loss.
        cum_loss += loss
        loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
        optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch:03d}, loss: {cum_loss/len(dataset):.4f}')
    csvwriter.writerow([epoch, (cum_loss/len(dataset)).cpu().detach().numpy()])
filename = "output1.1.csv"
filename_label = "output_label1.csv"
fields = ['a', 'b', ...]

#test function
def test(loader):
    model.eval()
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile, open(filename_label, 'w') as csvoutput:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvoutwriter = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        csvwriter.writerow(fields)
        csvoutwriter.writerow(fields)
        correct = 0
        for data in loader:  
            data = data.to(device)
            out = model(data) 
            correct += int((out.argmax(-1)==data.y.view(-1,1)).sum())
            for i  in range(10):
                csvwriter.writerow(out.cpu().detach().numpy()[i,:])
                csvoutwriter.writerow((data.y.cpu().detach()).numpy()[i,:])
    return correct / len(loader)  # Derive ratio of correct predictions.
model.train()
filename_train = "trainloss1.1.csv"
with open(filename_train, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(['Epoch', 'Loss'])
    

    for epoch in range(300): 
        train()
        test_acc = test(dataset) 
        print(f'Test Acc: {test_acc:.4f}')
```

I get this accuracy very low

```
Epoch: 000, loss: 4.2021
Test Acc: 9.9178
```

previously I tried changing the `correct` parameter in test data stating as

```
correct += int((out.argmax(-1)==data.y).sum())
```

which results in

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (12) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

I got this runtime error and tried

```
correct += int((out.argmax(-1)==data.y.view(-1,1)).sum())
```

but having very low accuracy as I stated. How can I fix this problem? Am I doing something wrong here?
My data size in loader is

```
Data(edge_attr=[18], edge_index=[2, 18], x=[10, 132], y=[10, 12])
```

Comment: Is your output classification into 12 outputs, and mutually exclusive? If so, then you have to do argmax to your labels, too. `correct += int((out.argmax(-1)==y.argmax(-1))`. If you just compare it to y, then you're checking if the output argmax is equal to 0, a LOT.

Comment: @jhso Tried it. But the output accuracy is like the one I tried. Accuracy comes like 4.8,4.7 etc. I am confused whats wrong

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a sum in my above code: `correct += (out.argmax(-1)==data.y.argmax(-1)).sum()`. Also, is it possible your model is just not performing that well?

Comment: @jhso Thanks. Still the same. But I tried  **correct += int((out.argmax(-1)==data.y.argmax(-1).view(-1,1)).sum())** and it shows a jump in accuracy from 3,4 to 35,40 etc. But still not high enough. What could I do else to improve it?

Comment: That is a significant boost! Unfortunately I don't know much about ChebConv layers, but maybe you should test different layer sizes, kernel sizes, and filterdepths. Even try adding linear layers after the convolution layers.